# Bootstrap applying grid to tough layout problem

Tags: layout, grid, bootstrap-grid

I started to learn bootstrap yesterday. I understand how to create simple grids with straight rows and cols. But this one is tough because columns are “unsymmetrical" if you know what I mean. Image:

[LAYOUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqPrP.png)

Every time im trying to create that I got stuck with one col or row too much

```html
   <div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 border">
        1
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 border">
        <div class="row border">2</div>
        <div class="row border">
            <div class="col-md-6 border">
                <div class="row border">3</div>
                <div class="row border">5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 border">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is not really possible in Bootstrap as of yet, and even if you tried, you'd still need to write a bit of custom CSS. In my opinion, you're better off writing a custom layout using CSS Grid.

Comment: It went through my mind, but your comment is making me sure now. Thank you!